# C++17 std::optional and std::ostringstream

Tags: c++, c++17

Consider this very simple code:

```
#include <optional>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
  std::optional<std::ostringstream> opt;
  std::ostringstream o;
  opt = std::optional<std::ostringstream> {o};
}
```

I'm simply trying to make an `optional` string stream (originally, I was trying to make an optional `struct`, which contains a field that is an `ostringstream`: as soon as I have this in the struct, the same problem arises).

It looks like it is impossible to compile it, while the same code works for example when `std::ostringstream` is replaced by an `std::string`.

The error message from g++ on Linux is extremely long, with several 3-line-long candidate names, but starts with this:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'std::optional<std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream<char> >::optional(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'
   opt = std::optional<std::ostringstream> {o}
```

The Microsoft C++ compiler (v. 19) gives a similar message:

```
error C2440: '<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'std::optional<std::ostringstream>'
note: No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
```

I suppose that there is some property of `ostringstream` that makes it incompatible with being optional, but I can't understand what is the exact underlying problem.

Comment: Streams can't be copied. And you try to copy a stream. What is the real, actual and underlying problem you try to solve with this? Please ask about that directly.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Ah, simply that... for some reason I was intuitively considering the ostringstream to behave more like a string than a stream, so didn't even think about it. That's the answer then!

Comment: If you don't need to store an existing object in `std::optional` then `std::make_optional` will help you work with non-copyable types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the stream is not copyable, you have to `std::move` the object into the optional:

```cpp
  opt = std::optional<std::ostringstream> { std::move(o) };
```

Note that `o` shouldn't be used after that.

If you don't want to create the temporary `o` variable, you can also initialize directly by passing `{}` to default initialize the stream:

```cpp
  opt = std::optional<std::ostringstream> { {} };
```